Proof of the Esseén Concentration Inequality in Tao's Notes
I've reproduced the proof of the Esseén Concentration Inequality below. (Pg. 3 and 4 in these notes). I've asked two questions in-line.

Proposition $2.1$: (Esseén concentration inequality). For any $\varepsilon > 0$ and $\phi_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$
\left| \{ x \in J : |\phi(x) - \phi_0| \leq \varepsilon \} \right| \lesssim \varepsilon \int_0^{1/\varepsilon} |I(\lambda)| \, d\lambda. \tag{$\ast$}
$$
Proof. Using the various invariances we can normalise $\phi_0 = 0$ and $\varepsilon = 1$, and reduce to showing that
$$
\left| \{ x \in J : |\phi(x)| \leq 1 \} \right| \lesssim \int_{-1}^{1} |I(\lambda)| \, d\lambda. \tag{1}
$$


The integral on the right should be $\int_{0}^{1} |I(\lambda)| \, d\lambda$, i.e., the lower limit is $0$ instead of $-1$, right?


Now let $\psi$ be a bump function adapted to $[-1, 1]$. Observe from Fubini's theorem that
$$
\int_{-1}^{1} \psi(\lambda) I(\lambda) \, d\lambda = \int_J \check{\psi}(\phi(x)/2\pi) \, dx. \tag{2}
$$
One can easily choose $\psi$ so that $\check{\psi}$ is non-negative, and bounded from below by an absolute constant on $[-2\pi, 2\pi]$ (e.g., some variant of the Fejér kernel will work). The claim then easily follows.


I believe $\psi \equiv 0$ outside $[-1,1]$ (or $[0,1]$, assuming I am right about the limits.) I understand that $(2)$ follows from Fubini's theorem. Next, how do we choose $\psi$ so that $\check{\psi} \gtrsim 1$? Even if we choose such $\psi$, I can't see how the claim $(1)$ follows.

